# Non-trivial lower bound on the number of "Graph Diagonals"

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, np

The definition of *Graph Diagonals*, that are the subject of this question, is based on the notions of *crossing edges* and on *connected graphs*:

Two edges $AC$ and $BD$ of a complete, symmetric and weighted graph are said to be *crossing* (each other) iff

  $A$, $B$, $C$ and, $D$ are distinct vertices and

  $AC+BD > AB+CD$ and  
  $AC+BD > AD+BC$

An edge $AB$ of a complete, symmetric and weighted graph,is then defined to be a *diagonal* of the graph iff

  removing from the graph all edges that are crossing edge $AB$ and

  removing vertices $A$ and $B$

disconnects the graph

One important property of those graph diagonals is that they can't appear in an optimal tour through all vertices of the graph.

From some experiments I observed that at least every 6th edge was such a diagonal and with increasing number of vertices almost all vertices were adjacent to such a diagonal.

My question is, whether the lower bound of $n(n+1)/12$ diagonals can be confirmed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "symmetric" complete graph?

Comment: "symmetric" means that the edges are undirected (I had the symmetric TSP in mind, but I agree that I should have been more precise here).
A complete graph is one where every pair of vertices corresponds to an edge with an associated weight.  

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Next question: Does AC mean the weight of the edge from vertex A to vertex C? If so, then setting all weights to 1 gives zero diagonals...